# XPath: Select node based on depth of descendant node type

Tags: xml, xpath, descendant

I need to return the string "A1" or the string "A2" dependent upon the maximum depth of the "B" nodes beneath their containing nodes:

```
<xmlDoc>
 <A>A1
  <B>
   <B>
    <B>
    </B>
   </B>
  </B>
  <B>
  </B>
</A>
<A>A2
 <B>
  <B>
  </B>
 </B>
  <B>
   <B>
   </B>
  </B>
 </A>
</xmlDoc>
```

The `descendant` axis does not seem appropriate to determine the "depth" of the B nodes (Ex: `/xmlDoc/A[count(descendant::B)>2]`). The "A" node containing the string "A1" has a maximum "B" node depth of 3 but seems to have 4 "descendant" "B" nodes...

How would one construct an XPath expression to return the string "A1" based upon the "3 deep" occurrence of the "B" nodes in the first "A" node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descendant counts all children of the node. If you want chain of B nodes, write it so

```
/xmlDoc/A[B[B[B]]]
```

Comment: Thanks! There isn't an axis that would accomplish the same by chance? Nothing was popping up on Google, but I definitely wanted to ask before I gave up!

Comment: there is no standard axis for such query, as I understand

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hopefully this will prove useful to others as well.

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck